# AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I'm just not able to set LinearLayout parameters programatically. Everything I try, I get this exact exception.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) outerLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.bottomMargin = 50;
outerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);


java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

I have no idea why, but it seems I just can't get LinearLayout.LayoutParams on a view. `outerLayout` is my LinearLayout I am instantiating it with findViewById(). I've tried importing different things but no luck.

Here is my xml that represents one item in a list view. `outer_item_layout` is the layout i am calling getLayoutParams() on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/outer_item_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/modeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_speed"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
            tools:ignore="InvalidId" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/custom_mode_speed_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout xml.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the bottom margin programmatically?

Comment: If it is really a requirement, then you can add another LinearLayout container inside your root LinearLayout and manipulate that.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a view's `getLayoutParams()` call is not dependent on the type of the view, but rather on the type of **that view's parent**. So, even though `outerLayout` is a `LinearLayout`, its layout params could be anything.

It seems that your `outerLayout` view is being hosted inside some sort of `ListView`, which is why the result of `outerLayout.getLayoutParams()` is of type `AbsListView.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Yes, it is hosted inside a ListView. I am trying to get these LinearLayout parameters inside a list view adapter. Is there any way I could get the parameters of a layout instead of it's parent (ListView)?

Comment: @orglce The purpose of `LayoutParams` is to provide information to the parent about how to lay out the child, so there's not really any concept of "the parameters of a layout instead of its parent"... only the parent cares about laying out the child. You could perhaps solve this specific problem by setting the bottom _padding_ of the LinearLayout, rather than the bottom _margin_.